# changing relative times to actual dates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have currently a dataframe I created by scraping google news headlines. One of my columns is "Time", which refers to time of publication of an article.

Unfortunately, for recent articles, google news uses a "relative" date, e.g., 6 hours ago, or 1 day ago instead of Nov 1, 2017.

I really want to convert these relative dates to be consistent with the other entries (so they also say Nov 12, 2017, for example), but I have no idea where to even start on this.

My thoughts are to maybe make a variable which represents todays date, and then do some kind of search through the dataframe for stuff which doesn't match my format, and then to subtract those relative times with the current date. I would also have to make some sort of filter for stuff which has "hours ago" and just have those equal the current date.

I don't really want a solution but rather a general idea of what to read to try to solve this. Am I supposed to try using numpy?

Example of some rows:

```
     Publication    Time    Headline
0   The San Diego Union-Tribune     6 hours ago     I am not opposed to new therapeutic modalities...
1   Devon Live  13 hours ago    If you're looking for a bargain this Christmas...
15  ABS-CBN News    1 day ago   Now, Thirdy has a chance to do something that ...
26  New York Times  Nov 2, 2017     Shepherds lead their sheep through the centre ...
```

Comment: Add the sample dataframe please

Comment: Sorry - just edited!

Comment: Making "hours ago" equal the current date will get you in trouble if it crosses back into yesterday.  Better just to convert to datetime format using the method you described for all cases.

Comment: Oh...You're right. That will create some problems. I guess I would need to know the present time and date then subtract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should work.  Use Pandas `Timedelta` to subtract relative dates from the current date.

For example, given your sample data as:

```
Publication;Time;Headline
The San Diego Union-Tribune;6 hours ago;I am not opposed to new therapeutic modalities
Devon Live;13 hours ago;If you're looking for a bargain this Christmas
ABS-CBN News;1 day ago;Now, Thirdy has a chance to do something that
New York Times;Nov 2, 2017;Shepherds lead their sheep through the centre
```

Read in the data from the clipboard (although you could just as easily substitute with `read_csv()` or some other file format):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=";")
```

For the dates that are already in date format, Pandas is smart enough to convert them with [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
absolute_date = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, errors="coerce")

absolute_date
0          NaT
1          NaT
2          NaT
3   2017-11-02
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

For the relative dates, once we drop the "ago" part, they're basically in the right format to convert with [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#parsing):

```
relative_date = (datetime.today() - 
                 df.Time.str.extract("(.*) ago", expand=False).apply(pd.Timedelta))

relative_date
0   2017-11-11 17:05:54.143548
1   2017-11-11 10:05:54.143548
2   2017-11-10 23:05:54.143548
3                          NaT
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now fill in the respective `NaN` values from each set, absolute and relative (updated to use [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), via Jezrael's answer):

```
date = relative_date.combine_first(absolute_date)

relative_date
0   2017-11-11 17:06:29.658925
1   2017-11-11 10:06:29.658925
2   2017-11-10 23:06:29.658925
3   2017-11-02 00:00:00.000000
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Finally, pull out just the date from the datetime:

```
date.dt.date
0    2017-11-11
1    2017-11-11
2    2017-11-10
3    2017-11-02
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was unbelievably simple - I had no idea pandas had this functionality already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) first and then use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
#create dates
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], errors='coerce')
#create times
times = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].str.extract('(.*)\s+ago', expand=False))
#combine final datetimes
df['Time'] = (pd.datetime.now() - times).combine_first(dates).dt.floor('D')

print (df)
                   Publication       Time  \
0  The San Diego Union-Tribune 2017-11-12   
1                   Devon Live 2017-11-11   
2                 ABS-CBN News 2017-11-11   
3               New York Times 2017-11-02   

                                         Headline  
0  I am not opposed to new therapeutic modalities  
1  If you're looking for a bargain this Christmas  
2   Now, Thirdy has a chance to do something that  
3   Shepherds lead their sheep through the centre
```

---

```
print (df['Time'])
0   2017-11-12
1   2017-11-11
2   2017-11-11
3   2017-11-02
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: `combine_first()` is new to me, thanks for the lesson.